# Custom c# collection class sorting by multiple properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I am sorting a custom class as follows, which is sorted by FirstHalfPoints:

```
 var firstHalfTables = new FirstHalfTableCollection();
        firstHalfTables.PopulateForSeason(SeasonId);
        firstHalfTables.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.FirstHalfPoints.CompareTo(t2.FirstHalfPoints));
        firstHalfTables.Reverse();
        FirstHalfTableRepeater.DataSource = firstHalfTables;
        FirstHalfTableRepeater.DataBind();
```

I also need to sort by a two further fields 'GD' - Goal Difference and 'GF' - Goals For- after this initial sort by 'FirstHalfPoints'

So the finished collection will be sorted by FirstHalfPoints, then by GD, then by GF.

Can anyone help me out with multiple sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ, which often makes the code more readable:

```
var firstHalfTables = new FirstHalfTableCollection();
firstHalfTables.PopulateForSeason(SeasonId);
var firstHalfTablesProcessed = (from table in firstHalfTables
                                orderby table.FirstHalfPoints, table.GD, table.GF
                                select table).Reverse()
FirstHalfTableRepeater.DataSource = firstHalfTablesProcessed;
```

Or you could make your comparison delegate return the proper sorting (probably better as normal function than lambda):

```
int FirstHalfTableComparison(FirstHalfTable t1, FirstHalfTable t2)
{
    int result = t1.FirstHalfPoints.CompareTo(t2.FirstHalfPoints);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        result = t1.GD.CompareTo(t2.GD);

        if (result == 0)
            result = t1.GF.CompareTo(t2.GF);
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can use that like this:

```
firstHalfTables.Sort(FirstHalfTableComparison);
```

Comment: Thanks I went with the first option here, exactly as you have written it, many thanks for the help on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use direct LINQ expressions: "OrderBy" and "ThenBy" too: [MSDN Sorting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546145.aspx)

OR

you have to extent your comparison. You have to remember: `a.CompareTo(b)` should return -1 if a is "smaller" than b, 0 if they are equal and +1 if a is "bigger" than b.
So try the following:

```
private void Compare(YourRow a, YourRow b)
{
   let v = a.FirstHalfPoints.CompareTo(b.FirstHalfPoints);
   if (v != 0) return v;

   v = a.GD.CompareTo(b.GD);
   if (v != 0) return v;

   return a.GF.CompareTo(b.GF);
}
```

and call `Sort` with this function.

Comment: Also, don't forget to implement the [IComparable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx)

Comment: you don't have to when there is an override of sort like in this case

Comment: `CompareTo()` doesn't have to return just -1, 0 or 1. It can return any `int`. I hope you don't rely on that when you write your code (you don't in the code you posted).

Comment: no I don't - as you can read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx#Y228 it's a matter of bigger and less than zero so plus/minus one seems like a canonical choice to me ...

Comment: Thanks alot CKoenig for this, I went with the first option so I will edit with the update. UPDATE: didnt see the post below which has the code I used exactly so no need for me to post it. Thanks  again for your help on this.